# await function inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to create a new Promise inside an async function.
Inside this Promise, i'd like to call another async function which will call some async stuff (scrape the HTML from a web page).

Here's my code :

```
 async extractProductUrlFromHTML(html) {
    const products = html(`h2.product-name`).toArray();
    let extracted = [];
    let promises = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
        const element = products[index];
        let productUrl = element.children[0].attribs.href;
        const productProm = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {               
                console.log("process");
                const product = await this.getProductInfos(productUrl);
                console.log("resolving")
                resolve(product);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error)
            }

        })
        promises.push(productProm);

    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((prods) => {
        console.log("promises ok", prods)
        extracted.push(prods);
        return (extracted);
    })
}
```

And here's how the function is called :

```
async scrapeAllProducts({ request, response }) {
    let extractedProducts = []

    //get the html page
    const html = await AxiosService.getHTML('http://www.ubagcollection.com/fr/ubag.html?limit=36')
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    let pagesToScrape = await this.extractPagination($);
    pagesToScrape.push(`http://www.ubagcollection.com/fr/ubag.html?limit=36`)

    for (let index = 0; index < pagesToScraep.length; index++) {
        const url = pagesToScrape[index];
        let html = await AxiosService.getHTML(url);
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log("start extraction")
        const products = await this.extractProductUrlFromHTML($);
        console.log('product extracted from page :' + index)
        extractedProducts.push(products);
    }
    console.log("all is extracted", extractedProducts)
    ... bla bla bla
```

My problem is that at the moment all my promises are created, I can see the "product extraced from page : ... ", way before the program finished to work...

here's the sequence I can see when I run my script :

> start extraction
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> process
> product extracted from page :1

each time a promise is created, I log 'process', and I should see the "resolving" log when my async function has finished her job, which is not the case here.

Comment: Can you add `console.error(error);` before `reject(error)` in `extractProductUrlFromHTML` to check if any error occurs? When doing this what is the resulting output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed my problem.
I drop a code sample, maybe it might be useful for someone.

```
    let extracted = [];
    let promises = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < products.length; index++) {
        const element = products[index];
        let productUrl = element.children[0].attribs.href;
        const productProm = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                await utils.timeout(utils.getRandomInt(1000,4000))
                const product = await this.getProductInfos(productUrl);
                resolve(product);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error)
            }

        })
        promises.push(productProm);

    }
    let prods = await Promise.all(promises)
    extracted.push(prods);
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do it like this. You don't need to wrap those operations in a Promise. You could just extract that logic in the promise to a different async function. Also, if you reject that Promise, there's nothing in the part where you `await Promise.all(promises)` to catch it, so you would have an uncaught exception. Also, the way you have the code written here, it would process the products sequentially, not concurrently, so it will take much longer. It would probably be better to map over them, transforming the array of products into an array of promises running concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can clean up your promises a little. You don't need to wrap `getProductInfos` in a promise. You are `await`-ing it, so I'm assuming it returns a promise. There's no need to await a promise just to wrap it in another promise and resolve it.

Maybe something more like:

```
async extractProductUrlFromHTML(html) {
  try {
    const products = html(`h2.product-name`).toArray() || [];
    let extracted = [];
    let promises = products.map(element => {
      let productUrl = element.children[0].attribs.href;
      return this.getProductInfos(productUrl); // assuming getProductInfos returns a promise
    });

    const results = await Promise.all(promises); // need to await the Promise.all
    extracted.push(results); // Do you really want to push the array of results into another array? You'll have [[productInfo1, productInfo2, ...]]
    return extracted;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```